# Rube Goldberg Science Project

Tags: electricity

I am a normal mom who needs to figure out how electricity works. We all know light bulbs create heat and we need that heat to melt a very thin plastic string to move our machine along. The problem that I am having is the rules state "No electric device may have or use an electric potential difference of more than 9 volts. I am pretty sure (if youtube has explained it to me) that I can only use a 9 volt battery to power any electrical currents. I am finding that this is not enough power to heat a light bulb hot enough to melt my string.

So I need help figuring this out. How do I melt a thin plastic string only being able to use a 9 volt battery. I was thinking of making a heating coil, but I don't know how to do that and I don't know how to incorporate that into my rube goldberg machine. Because I don't know how I could activate the coil properly.

So ANY ideas or assistance with this problem would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a safety thing, they don't want you using mains electricity and killing yourself. It's going to be somewhat difficult to get a 9V battery to melt plastic (and be able to do it multiple times), as 9V batteries have a high internal resistance and a low capacity. You might see if a switch mode power supply would be allowed and use one of those, as they can output much more power.

Comment: (1) What is the "string" material and diameter? (2) Can you check the melting point - assuming it's a plastic? Answering these two will give us a target temperature and a rough estimate of the power (watts) required. (3) How will melting the string move the vehicle? (4) How many times or times per minute will we have to melt a string? Answering these two will enable us to calculate the battery power required. Add the info into your question rather than in the comments. Welcome to EE.SE!

Comment: This project sounds like it has burn and fire hazards that dwarf the voltage concern in the rules.

Comment: If more than 9V is forbidden, you can use a 6V lead acid battery, it'll have enough power to set things on fire just fine ;)

Comment: 9 volt batteries are a poor choice for this kind of thing.  They cannot deliver very much current, and can't deliver if for very long.  You need high capacity batteries.  Use 4 D cells in series to get 6 volts.  Those can deliver several amperes of current for a fairly long time.  6 cells in series will get you about 9 volts, but some nit picker might decide that they can deliver a bit more than 9V when new.

Comment: It's going to depend on the thickness of the string and the type of plastic used, since they all have different melting temperatures. It's also not clear if you have to just melt it at one point so it snaps, or for some reason a considerable length has to be melted. Just off the top of my head, if the string were stretched over the edge of a TO220 transistor package, for many plastics shoving a high current from 9V through it might generate enough heat to break it.

Comment: I'm not going to complain about the 9 V battery. It is what you have. So I'll just assume you are stuck with it. This means you need to be able to heat something up quickly and for a short time and with low net energy. Since you have the string already (wish we could see it), you probably need to consider wrapping a wire around it directly. You will need to find some nichrome wire that is 28 gauge or smaller (such as 30 gauge, 32 gauge ...) and about \$2\:\Omega\$ length. Try to make several turns around the string. Hook it up with copper wire from the battery. See if that works acceptably.

Comment: That will heat up the Alkaline battery if left on and live a very short life

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That proposes "left on" is true. Since this is Rube Goldberg, I believe it is obvious it is NOT left on and that there must be some earlier event that triggers the heating. So I think the assumption is false, and therefore the conclusions do not necessarily follow.

Comment: Steel wool will get red hot with a 9V battery, I would guess wrapping the plastic line around a 1/4 W resistor would also work

Comment: Use a lantern battery. Its 6 volts, with amps of current output.

Answer (score 1):

The string needs to have a very low melting temperature. The wire would have to be much much smaller than  human hair for 9V to get 10 watts into 8 Ohms in a short strand. (0.008mm)  But that hair would be the ideal plastic string for a fast break.

190–350 °C is common for nylon.

A 9V battery may not be an excellent choice

A 10 Ohm resistor might  over 160'C but then the epoxy starts to smoke (toxic).

A tiny lightbulb filament but it has to get hot enough to burn a plastic thread then the plastic starts smoking on the glass. (toxic)

Brown garden hemp string may work but the light bulb needs more power and it might take a minute or so unless you have a very thin filament.

If you can find a 9V high power flashlight, it "might be borderline hot to melt" with some fire-proof insulation underneath.

[image]

But most likely unless it can melt in boiling water, it wont work.

### added

When my kids were small we used a 12V lattern battery to power an igniter (heater wire) for starting a solid rocket. A Hobby shop will carry these small glow igniter wires (  which if you have a momentary switch to use it wrapped around a wooden match, that will work. Safety of mounting the match is important. Mount it inverted so the flame doesn't burn the wire as much and falls into a bucket of water.

Comment: do i have to use a match with the igniter wire?

Comment: Unless you can get a Lithium ion pack or a stronger batter and a tiny filament Nichrome igniter wire, you will have a hard time to burn the plastic string. due to lack of stored heat energy in a 9V cell and finding the optimum heater wire.

Answer (score 1):

Disposable electrocautery pens use a few AA batteries,and smoke human tissue.

Comment: How would we connect the return pad, though? Then again, a disposable pen might come with a disposable pad.  Maybe the bag that the pen comes in unfolds to form a return pad.

Comment: @NickAlexeev  It's actually heat cautery.  There is no return pad.

Comment: Let's go for pen-sized Bovie.  It's a Rube Godlberg challenge after all.

Answer (score 1):

use a 6V turn-signal or brake lamp. they get plenty hot. run it from a 6V lantern battery.

for the lamp go to a place that sells motor-cycle parts.

Comment: They could even crack off the bulb glass and directly use the filiment. At least for a one shot plastic string melt.

Answer (score 1):

A heating coil is a length of resistance wire wound into a coil.

You could salvage a short piece of heating wire from a broken heating appliance (eg: toaster, hair dryer) and power it from a single D cell,  you'll probably find that a D cell can heat a half-inch piece of resistance wire to red-hot in half a second.

This is nichrome wire, it's also used in "vape" machines and short pieces can be purchased for a few bucks on line if you don't have any junk appliances on-hand.

Answer (score 0):

You almost can certainly achieve what you want, if that means heating up and melting the wire. Even a relatively weak \$9\:\text{V}\$ can be made to do this given the right diameter and length of nichrome wire wrapped around the plastic string -- though whether or not it is really achievable will depend more on the diameter of your string, the quality of your thermal contact to it, etc.

I'm guessing, though you don't explicitly say, that you cannot plan to use anything plugged into the mains supply. And that you do have to use some kind of battery. Since this is a science project, you may also not be permitted to use batteries that use liquids like sulfuric acid, but must instead use batteries that are considered "zero risk" to use. This might eliminate LiPo batteries from use, depending on the perspective of those planning the event. You also may have other devices that you didn't discuss here, that also work using the \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery voltage and which would not work as well for some reason if you are using a lower voltage.

So let's address the battery situation first, on the assumption you aren't permitted access to mains power. You need to decide upon a voltage range that is acceptable. We know it has to be \$\le 9\:\text{V}\$. But there may be a lower limit for your own specific project that you have not mentioned. Once you know the voltage range, you also need to find out the allowable chemistries. I'm guessing that lead-acid batteries are probably off the table. And probably anything else with potentially hazardous liquids in them. You may also be limited in other ways. You need to figure that out.

Assuming you are limited to commercial, off the shelf, alkaline chemistries, then you still have the option of using a \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery or else using some combination of AA, AAA, C, or D cells to reach whatever voltage you want. There are battery holders that will support various combinations of these using springs to hold them in place. So all of these may be options and very convenient.

My recommendation is to use the largest allowable size and just stack them up to the voltage you want. If you are allowed space for six D cells, then by all means use that. These will be far, far more capable in terms of supplying current (amps) than the smaller batteries can handle. But work out what you feel you can afford to use in the project. This choice, in fact, will have a lot to do with what you next do regarding heating up the plastic string to melt it. I'll explain in a moment.

If you are stuck using the standard \$9\:\text{V}\$ alkaline battery, these have approximately \$1-2\:\Omega\$ internal series resistance. This limits the maximum current you can get out of them. Their voltage also varies a lot, because they are just a tightly packed stack of six small \$1.5\:\text{V}\$ batteries. Their output voltage will vary from about \$9.4\:\text{V}\$ (quickly brought down closer to \$9\:\text{V}\$ under some early use) when fresh down to about \$\lt 8\:\text{V}\$ when getting "mostly useless."

It turns out that to get the maximum power out of any battery, you want the external resistance to be about the same as the internal resistance. So if you are using a \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery, I'd recommend using something that has about \$2\:\Omega\$ of resistance. This will match up reasonably well with that kind of battery. And with \$9\:\text{V}\$ batteries, I really do think you need to maximize the power in the load because you need every little bit you can get.

However, if you are using D cells in a stack-up, then a much, much lower resistance might be indicated for maximum power. But in this case, you don't care nearly as much. Here, you just need to get the necessary heating. And here, once again, I think \$2\:\Omega\$ of resistance is quite workable (and will get hotter than it would with the \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery.)

The only convenient material, readily available and that has the right resistivity, is nichrome. And in this case, I think you need about 28-30 gauge wire. With just an amp or two, this will rapidly heat up to sufficient temperature to melt plastic (which is usually below \$260^\circ\:\text{C}\$.) There are many interesting tables at this Wiki site: [nichrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome). So take a look at those. They even document helical (wrapping the wire around your string) structures there. Nice!

So regardless of your choice of battery system, I think you need some nichrome wire. And it needs to be fairly thin, as well.

Once you have some, try wrapping your string and test out the results. I'm betting that you can get there from here, even with the \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery. But certainly with stacks of AA, AAA, C, or D cells.

---

Note that I'm assuming your Rube Goldberg device triggers the circuit to connect the \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery to your heating circuit at some point during the "show." It might be worth some trouble to work out a timed switch of some kind, too. Something that engages the load for a specific period of time needed to heat the wire sufficiently, but which then shuts the circuit off some seconds later. (Just keep it ON long enough and no longer.)

I've posted circuits to do this. Others have, as well. If you can build such a circuit (mine requires one BJT and one MOSFET), then this would be worth considering. It will also make the entire process safer, I believe, and less prone to human error or forgetfulness. But it will certainly save the battery life, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here.  Let me quote the relevant text from the question: "No electric device may have or use an electric potential difference of more than 9 volts."

Nowhere do I see mention of being limited to using only a battery.

I see several options here.

1) Battery pack made up of 6 cells in series.  These could be "AA", "C", "D" cells.  Suitable battery holders are available at Radio Shack or many of the electronics suppliers.  Modern Alkaline "D" cells are good for almost 18 AH or more.

2) Disassemble a Vap pen and salvage the heating element and battery.  This is usually only a single Li-Ion cell (usually 18650 size).  The included heating element should get hot enough to melt plastic.

3) Use an off-the-shelf wall-wart or line-lump power supply.  Most cell-phone chargers put out around 5 Vdc at 2 Amps or better.  That's 10 watts of energy - that can heat a length of suitable resistance wire hot enough to melt plastic.

4) Use an off-the-shelf portable power bank.  Same results as (3) above.

5) Use something like a model train transformer.  Usually good for anywhere from 10 to 30 Watts.

Comment: Obviously the mains supplies violate the voltage limit on the input side.

Answer (score -1):

If 9 Volt batteries are the only ones allowed, then just use multiple ones in parallel. They've just specified the voltage neglecting to mention anything about current. I remember from school more than 20 years ago that we used 9V battery powered hot-wire foam cutters to cut some polystyrene sheets. The wire was nicrome.

Comment: 9v is a *limit* not a requirement.

Comment: I am sure the requirement is to not exceed 9v. So with the current, will the current be faster if I use multiple 9volt batteries and still not exceed the 9 volt rule?

Comment: Does current speed effect voltage?

Comment: I did a school project where they told me I could only use batteries of 9V or less... Did you know you can power quite a decent VALVE guitar amp with 40 9V batteries in series and a couple of sets of parallel D cells for the heaters. I did learn the hard way that 9V battery cases are not designed to stand off 380 odd volts. There does not seem to be an equivalent getout here, apart from the failing to specify a current limit, model rocket 'igniters' would be worth a look, or nicrome and a D size rechargable cell or two (Plenty of available current there).

Comment: 3 RECHARGABLE C or D size batteries will provide plenty of power for melting a string (use fishing line), even if you use thin copper wire for the heater (Nicrome is better in all ways however). The rechargable thing is important because those things can provide a much higher current then ordinary batteries.

Comment: Actually I have to agree, that with the internal resistance of 9V batteries, its better for currents sense to just use some big C/D batteries, that will have much less power anyway, overall.

Comment: https://makezine.com/2012/03/20/the-secret-life-of-disposable-cautery-pens/

Answer (score -1):

I recommend going to a camera store and asking for some flashbulbs.  The camera store people will probably be happy to help you select one that will work well with 9V. Then carefully crack off the glass by rolling it between a plate and a cutting board with a bit of sand or salt on it for grit. The filament will “poof” hot when power is applied. If the rules allow, you can include a match head for a bit longer heat.